# LCD suddenly increases contrast

Tags: windows-7, lcd

I'm running on a Windows 7-64 bit, Intel HD Graphics with a resolution 1366x768 pixels.
What I've noticed is that when I'm using my laptop on battery power and not plugging it on a power source, is that the computer screen suddenly increases its contrast on just a particular color which is black or any dark color, but when it's plugged in, it doesn't show the problem that I have. Any idea what's happening

Comment: Are you sure it's contrast, and not the automatic brightness settings? Most laptops will set brightness to "automatic" when on battery and to 100% when plugged in.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the contrast, when I check the power options, when that event happens, the brightness is still the same the last time I set it.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it can still be the case that the hardware changes this setting without informing Windows. Do you have any *quick keys* on your laptop that allows to change the brightness (e.g. on HP laptops, it's Fn+F9 or Fn+F10). If you press them when on battery, does it change and look similar when the laptop is connected?

Comment: I've actually set the same brightness of my laptop when it's plugged in or unplugged, yes it has quick keys (Fn+left/right arrow keys), and I basically see changes whens its connected or not. Its not really the contrast but the hue and saturation increases on a particular color which is black.